# Error while removing a div with a particular id using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to remove a div with a particular **id** using BeautifulSoup.

Code snippet:

```
from django import template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='reset_html_styles')
def reset_html_styles(value):
    # value = '<div class="test"><div dir="ltr" id="divRplyFwdMsg"><p>Some paragraph</p></div></div>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(value, 'html5lib')
    soup.find('div', id='divRplyFwdMsg').decompose()
    return str(soup)
```

which is giving me this error output:

```
Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'
```

I faced no problem while removing divs using class names.
I'm using `python 3.6.5`, `django 2.0` and `beautifulsoup4 4.6.0` version.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error. If I `print(soup)` after running your snippet I get the `html` string without that specific `div`, which means it's working as intended. Edit: I'm running `python 3.6.6` and `beautifulsoup4 4.6.0`

Comment: Yes, It finds the html content. But when I use `decompose()` to remove that particular html from soup, it gives error.

Comment: Could you please post the exact code you're running + full traceback? I want to see exactly what line is raising the error.

Comment: @Rakib Are you calling the line with `decompose` multiple times? In that case `find` will not manage to produce a result and you will get the error message you describe.

Comment: @hgazibara No, I am calling the line one time only

Comment: @TomasFarias I have updated the code portion in the question. I am creating a custom template tag in Django.

Comment: does it still happen with your greyed out value?

Comment: @bobrobbob unfortunately yes. It works in plain python console. But I can't get it to work inside this django template filter.

Comment: it should work with your static value. your snippet is too simplified, show more code